# Duplicate headers in primefaces data table

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I use stickyHeader=true on primefaces data table I see two headers generated. Second is 5 rows below the actual header and it is happening on all my pages. Anybody had this issue and got it resolved?

```
<p:dataTable var="product" value="#{productBean.products}" stickyHeader="true">
<p:column headerText="Name">
    <h:outputText value="#{product.name}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Year">
    <h:outputText value="#{product.year}" />
</p:column>    
<p:column headerText="Active">
    <h:outputText value="#{product.active}" />
</p:column>
```

[image]

Comment: So the first thing you tried is the latest PF version to see if it has been fixed? And did you search for this problem? Has been discussed several years ago.

Comment: Agree with @Kukeltje look how many StickyHeader issues that have already been fixed over the years: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues?q=is%3Aissue+stickyheader+is%3Aclosed

Comment: Issue was not with PF, the data table was placed in a div which was positioned relative.
Anybody can easily reproduce the above issue just put the above code in a div with style `position: relative;`